# Firefox: Cursor doesn't disappear in fullscreen

Tags: firefox, mouse, cursor, fullscreen

Apologies if this is more of a Firefox forum question but I thought this may be a better place to post the question. Basically, Firefox does not auto hide the cursor when I go into fullscreen mode. I do not have any special extensions installed. I installed the full version of Ubuntu on my PC.

Comment: What do you define as the *full* version of Ubuntu.  You've not provided any release, nor desktop, server, or *specialist* release though *full* likely means it's a server or desktop system (`firefox` implies desktop) but we still don't know what release you're talking about.  Please clarify *full*

Comment: It is the desktop version. By "full", I meant during installation, I chose the option that had all the extras instead of the light version. 20.04.2 LTS